# DocuSign Connect Callback Failure

Tags: docusignapi

I'm running into the issue when I'm trying to test the callback with my public url in demo developer account, and I got this failure

> https://xxx.xxx.xxx/docusign/inbound/message :: Error - Connect Listener Uri reference to internal DocuSign sites is not allowed

However, when I'm testing with public webhook url from the website https://webhook.site/
and it's working properly.

Anyone knows what might cause the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error is misleading as it also occurs when you use a local address.

Your address must not be your local device, it must be a server on the internet and one that is not DocuSign IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://ngrok.com if you want to debug your localhost.